# Relationship between rank of binary matrix and the NOT operator

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-rank, binary

Let $A$ be a binary matrix. I'm looking for any information about the relationship between the rank of $A$ and the rank of NOT$(A)$, where NOT replaces all $0$s with $1$s, and vice-versa.

**What I know**

- These ranks can sometimes be equal. For example, applying the NOT operator to the identity matrix returns another full rank matrix.
- They can sometimes not be equal. For example, the matrix 
  \begin{equation*} A=
  \begin{bmatrix}
  1 & 0 \\
  1 & 1
  \end{bmatrix}
  \end{equation*}
  has rank $2$, but 
  \begin{equation*} \text{NOT}(A)=
  \begin{bmatrix}
  0 & 1 \\
  0 & 0
  \end{bmatrix}
  \end{equation*}
  has rank $1$.

**My questions**

Are there known relationships between the two ranks?

Comment: What is the NOT operator?

Comment: @Dzoooks Sorry about that, I've clarified this in the first paragraph. It flips $0$s and $1$s.

Comment: What does it do to numbers which are not 0 or 1?  Are entries of the matrices you're considering only 0 or 1?  There are only 16 2 $\times$ 2 matrices with entries as 0's or 1's.  Write them down!

Comment: I'm discussing binary matrices, so only $0$ and $1$.

Comment: The sum is rank 1, so you can shift the rank by 1 or have it the same, but that's it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $E$ is the $n \times n$ matrix of all $1$'s, $NOT(A) = E - A$.  Now $E$ has rank $1$, and in general $$\text{rank}(A)-\text{rank}(B) \le \text{rank}(A+B) \le \text{rank}(A) + \text{rank}(B)$$
Thus the rank of $NOT(A)$ differs from that of $A$ by at most $1$.

You gave an example where the ranks are equal, and one where $\text{rank}(NOT(A)) = \text{rank}(A) - 1$; interchange $A$ and $NOT(A)$ and you have an example where $\text{rank}(NOT(A)) = \text{rank}(A) + 1$.

Comment: This makes sense. Very clever! Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

It may help to notice that 
$$
\operatorname{not}
\begin{bmatrix} 
x_{11}       & x_{12}\\
x_{21}       & x_{22}\\
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix} 
1       & 1\\
1       & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}
-
\begin{bmatrix} 
x_{11}       & x_{12}\\
x_{21}       & x_{22}\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

and $\operatorname{rank}\begin{bmatrix}1\end{bmatrix}_{nn} = 1$.

since [$\operatorname{rank}(A+ B) \le \operatorname{rank}(A) + \operatorname{rank}(B)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/246941/prove-that-operatornameranka-operatornamerankb-ge-operatornamera), you can tell that
 $$\operatorname{rank}(\operatorname{not}(A)) \le \operatorname{rank}(A) + 1$$
and also
$$\operatorname{rank}(A) = \operatorname{rank}(\operatorname{not}(\operatorname{not}(A))) \le \operatorname{rank}(\operatorname{not}(A)) + 1$$
which means $$\operatorname{abs} \left(\ \operatorname{rank}(A) - \operatorname{rank}(\operatorname{not}(A)) \ \right) \le 1$$